# Continued Fractions for Irrational Numbers

Tags: number-theory

Let $a, b, y$ be irrational numbers satisfying $a<b<y$. If a and y have identical convergents $h0/k0, h1/k1, \ldots, hn/kn$, prove that $B$ also has these same convergents up to $hn/kn$.

I tried to use some form of induction and substitution to solve the problem.

Comment: can you tell us about your work so far?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the actual algorithm used
to generate the continued fractions.
When the algorithm generates
the convergents for $a$ and $y$,
see what happens to the convergents
for $b$.

Since $b$ is between $a$ and $y$
(odd choice of variables, btw),
the convergents for $b$
will be between those of $a$ and $y$.
Since those are equal, 
the convergents for $b$
must also be equal.